# cin buffer Issues in C++

Tags: c++, buffer, infinite-loop, cin, cout

I'm learning C++, so I don't fully understand what's going on with my code here, but from what I've been able to glean, it seems like it could be some kind of buffer issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

bool stopRun = true;
int height, average, total, count;
vector <int> heights;

int main ()
{
    while (stopRun)
    {
        cout << "Enter a height, or 'end' to quit: ";
        cin >> height;
        if (typeid(height).name() == "i")
        {
            heights.push_back(height);
            cout << heights[0];
            count++;
        }
        else if (typeid(height).name() == "i")
        {
            cout << "\nPlease enter an integer: ";
            continue;
        }
        if (count == 5)
        {
            stopRun = false;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < heights.size(); i++)
    {
        total += heights[i];
        cout << "\nTotal: " << total;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, this code will continuously output: "Enter a height, or 'end' to quit: ". In an earlier version, it would output: "Enter a height, or 'end' to quit: Please enter an integer: ".

What I think is going on is that my "cin >> height;" line is pulling in the output from "Please enter an integer: " and treating it as my input, which identifies it as not being of type integer, which starts the infinite loop.

How do I clear the input buffer so that it doesn't bring in cout statements? Or is that even the issue I'm experiencing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cin >> height;` If you enter something that is not an integer, `cin`will be in an error state. You need to clear the error and consume the bad input. [Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](//stackoverflow.com/a/5131654)

Comment: Another option is to read the input as a `std::string` and convert to `int` with [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: What's the purpose of the typeid's? They do not tell you anything about whether `cin` successfully read an integer. Besides, isn't the condition in the `if` and `else if` -branches the same?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to catch the string. If string is not "end" then convert to number inside try/catch

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function at the start of your program fflush(stdin). It will clear your input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to read an `int` and a `string` in the same line of code. I suggest you use `getline()` to read the input and try to convert the `string` to `int`.

```
std::string input;
while (heights.size() != 5) {
    cout << "Enter a height, or 'end' to quit: ";
    if (std::getline(cin, input)) {
        if (input == "end") break;
        try {
            heights.push_back(std::stoi(input));
        }
        catch (std::invalid_argument e) {
            cout << "\nPlease enter an integer: ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string(typeid(height).name()) == "i")
```

What you had wrong was the comparison of a pointer and string. Since typeid(height).name() returns a pointer to a c-string with the name for the object.